# How to step into second C# delegate in MonoDevelop?

Tags: c#, debugging, delegates

Let's say there is a code that defines C# delegate:

```
public delegate void RezScript(IClientAPI remoteClient, InventoryItemBase item, 
                               UUID transactionID, uint localID);
```

Also there is a delegate object being defined and called:

```
RezScript rezScriptHandler = OnRezScript;
...
rezScriptHandler += RelayRezScript;
...
if (rezScriptHandler != null) {
  rezScriptHandler(this, item, rezScriptx.InventoryBlock.TransactionID, 
                   rezScriptx.UpdateBlock.ObjectLocalID);
}
```

How do I step through both calls to `OnRezScript` and `RelayRezScript` in the MonoDevelop debugger? Step over will skip over all delegates, stepping into steps into first call and returns back to the next line after the call to delegate. How can I step through all delegates?

P.S. I could o'course rewrite the code to use `GetInvocationList()` and call each delegate separately in a for-loop, but the whole point is to keep the nice syntax while being able to debug it.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to debug event handlers instead of normal delegates.

Comment: Possibly. I am new to the delegates concepts, so I'm not sure about the terminology, but what you said sounds right. I am trying to step into all delegate handlers that are registered for a specific delegate object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I have found only one of doing it - setting a breakpoint at the entry of each function added delegate.